# Multi Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm learning Multi Threading at the moment, in C#, but as with all learning I like to learn best practices. At the moment the area seems fuzzy. I understand the basics, and I can create threads.

What should I look out for when creating multi threaded applications. Are there any set rules or best practices that I should know about? Or anything to remember in order to avoid slip ups down the line?

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: If you're using C# then you should consider using the Task Parallel Library. It allows you to think about Tasks and Barriers rather than threads and locks. It improves the abstraction.

Comment: @Ade Miller: This is great advice - I'll add that you can use the TPL and PLINQ in .Net3.5, too, by installing the Reactive Extensions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In addition to the [MSDN Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx), I'll add:

1. Don't make your own threads.  Prefer to use the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) (or the new [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(VS.100).aspx) Tasks).  Managing your own thread is rarely, if ever, the correct design decision.
2. Take extra care with UI related issues.  [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) (Windows Forms) and [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) (WPF), or use [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx).Current with Post/Send
3. Favor using the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) when appropriate.
4. Try to keep synchronization via locks to a minimum
5. Make sure to synchronize everything that requires synchronization
6. Favor the methods in the [Interlocked class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) when possible over locking

Once you get more advanced, and are trying to optimize, other things to look for:

1. Watch out for [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).  This is especially problematic when working with arrays, since every array write to any element in an array includes a bounds check in .NET, which in effect causes an access on the array near element 0 (just prior to element 0 in memory).  This can cause perf. to go downhill dramatically.
2. Beware of closure issues, especially when working in looping situations.  Nasty bugs can occur if you're closing on a variable in the wrong scope when making a delegate.

Answer (score 9):

[MSDN - Managed Threading Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx)

That MSDN Article does a really good job at touching on the danger areas and giving the best practices for managing/working around those areas.

Answer (score 5):

Since I have this open on another tab...

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

I'm only a couple chapters in but it was written by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

Are there things you should know about ?
Certainly.

Dangers:

- [Race Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)
- [Deadlocks](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~kjg/cs102/Notes/Deadlock/)

A usefull and interesting article can be found [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/)

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend that you start by digesting this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/.

Comment: It's good you brought that up. I printed that 80 page PDF and I'm going it through it now.